# Reverse Proxy with Api or Database for Auto Setup

Tags: docker, nginx, devops, reverse-proxy

i want to auto provision a containerized application by code. What i came around now is the case where i need a reverse proxy that serves subomains to the public and routes the requests ingress to specific containers. As its automated the reverse proxy needs to be able to set up new routes dynamically by api or reading new routes from a database. I see that nginx plus has an api that could be triggered programmatically during provisioning, but its a licensed feature. Are there any proven and recommendable alternatives?

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/) a try which is very developer friendly. Various options (file, kubernetes, docker, consul, and more) are supported. I use it successfully in many projects.

Comment: Thanks, on a first look that seems promising.